# Sum all like columns with the column name as one column, and the total in the other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some data similar to this:

```
col1 | col2
-----------
val1    1
val1    5
val1    7
val2    3
val2    1
val2    4
val3    8
```

What I would like is a query to produce something like this:

```
col1 | sum
----------
val1   13
val2   8
val3   8
```

I've tried doing this with complicated subqueries, but nothing is quite panning out. I think I may be overthinking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be all you need. This uses the aggregate `SUM` with a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT col1, SUM(col2)
FROM unicorns
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: Yup, I was completely over thinking it. I upvoted everyone, but I'm giving you the answer for the use of `unicorns`.

Comment: @ScottStafford These unicorns have stripes. `col1` refers to the stripes.

Answer (score 3):

```
select col1, sum(col2) as sum from table group by col1
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the aggregate function `sum()` with a `group by`:

```
select col1, SUM(col2) total
from yourtable
group by col1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3442/2)

Answer (score 2):

```
  Select col1, Sum(col2) sum
  From table
  Group By col1
```